# How can I monitor network stability over time via command line on a Mac?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, mac

I'm seeing some odd network issues on my new work computer. The IT dept says it's a problem with my network. But my other Mac isn't having any issues with networks even when it's directly on top of the work Mac. My Windows PC that's in the same room isn't having any connection issues. Everything is on wifi.

What can I can run in the background (Bash) that will give me some assessment of my wifi connection stability? I'd like to run it on my work Mac, personal Mac and Windows PC. Just to see if the work Mac is an outlier. I'll post a separate question for the Windows command if I can get something that works for Mac.

A similar question has already been asked but it has no answers.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a good packet sniffer that can (with experience) help determine dropped packets.

Comment: @john A packet sniffer won't help much here, as it does not show the transmission over the wire or the association/disassociation of APs.    A better, but still not great way of doing this (ie not something to run long term) might be to run a version of mtr in the background.   Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281398/how-do-i-see-a-log-of-wifi-connect-disconnect-events talks about how to see a log of disconnects which could be useful.   As an aside, I recently hooked up Ubiquity Unifi setup and I can see graphs showing per-device connectivity and related info.

Comment: A packet sniffer can only help if disconnections are frequent enough that they can be watched. That is why I suggested it. Your ideas are fine as well.